# Movie rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

Here is an image containing rebus puzzles about movies.

[image]

Have fun solving it.

Comment: So have all been sorted out other than "CANDYHERE"?

Comment: These are excellent! Keep up the good work.

Comment: A J, the issue you raised in a recent flag has been referred to the CMs to look into, as the tools available to moderators are unavailing. Hopefully you should hear something in a few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Top to Bottom, then Left to Right:

> First Wives' Club
> Dr. No
> Last Tango In Paris
> The Sweet Hereafter (Thanks @Khale_Kitha, I hadn't heard of that one)
> Four Weddings and a Funeral
> From Dusk 'Til Dawn
> School of Rock
> Brokeback Mountain

Comment: Only thing I can think of for the middle one is http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120255/

Comment: All of them are correct.

Answer (score 6):

From top left to bottom right:

> 1. The First Wives' Club
>  2. From Dusk to Dawn
>  3. ?
>  4. ?
>  5. School of Rock
>  6. Last Tango In Paris
>  7. 4 Weddings and A Funeral
>  8. Brokeback Mountain

Comment: Good. Find remaining ones.

Answer (score 3):

One of the missing ones, middle left:

> Dr. No

Comment: right. keep going