# Another attempt at movie rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, movies

After I received a good response to my [last movie rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47343/19658), and in the light of Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26: Rebus, here is another set of movie rebuses.

[image]

Have fun solving. And all suggestions are welcome.

Please don't forget to mention how you guessed it.

Comment: @A J I think it would be better to mention number of movies hidden. My guess is 9/3

Comment: There are 9. It's obvious why would I separate each one by lines.

Comment: Nice puzzles ;)

Answer (score 11):

**Partial answer**

3rd one:

> *Planet of the Apes* (letters spelling out EARTH, a planet, are hidden within the names of apes).

4th one:

> *The Fifth Element* (Boron is the fifth element in the periodic table).

5th one:

> *Murder by Numbers* (the numbers correspond to the letters M,U,R,D,E,R).

6th one:

> *The Return of the Jedi* (THEJEDI backwards or 're-turned').

Comment: All of them are correct.

Answer (score 11):

The 8th and final one:

> **Hunt For The Red October**
>  [Search=Hunt, 4=For, red 10 = Red October]

Answer (score 8):

I guess someone has to put them all together. I only found 3 so I thought I would let those who found more do it but since no one did, I will.

1

> There is something about Mary.
>  Self explanatory.

2

> Pushing Tin (Sn is the symbol of tin, which is being pushed) (Credit @Ankoganit)

3

> Planet of the Apes (letters spelling out EARTH, a planet, are hidden within the names of apes) (Credit @rand al'thor)

4

> The fifth element. Boron is the 5th element on the periodic table.(Thanks to the incredibly clever Will!)

5

> Murder by Numbers (the numbers correspond to the letters M,U,R,D,E,R) (Credit @rand al'thor)

6

> The Return of the Jedi (THEJEDI backwards or 're-turned') (Credit @rand al'thor)

7

> Snakes on a Plane (names of snakes on Boeing 777) (Credit @Ankoganit)

8

> Hunt For The Red October [Search=Hunt, 4=For, red 10 = Red October] (Credit @Walt)

9

> Groundhog day. February 2 is the day that is repeated.

Comment: All of them are correct.

Comment: 4 should be The Fifth Element

Answer (score 5):

**PARTIAL**

3 is:

> looks like EARTH. (SMall-letters make earth)

5 is:

> MURDER by numbers (Yes, i had to google it) (Use A-Z as 1-26)

Comment: Not that close, but yes in right direction.Think hard.

Comment: It's a movie rebus. You have to guess the movie names correctly.

Comment: Earthlings I think.

Comment: @AJ Um, MURDER is a movie.. But, I guess there may be something else

Answer (score 5):

#### Partial:

1st:

> There's something about Mary  (SOMETHING written about MARY)

2nd:

> Pushing Tin  (Sn is the symbol of tin, which is being pushed)

5th:

> Murder by Numbers  (numbers corresponding to the letters of MURDER)

7th:

> Snakes on a Plane  (names of snakes on Boeing 777)

Comment: Going in the right direction. All of them is correct. Try solving remaining ones.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility for 9:

> The Australian film "20-20 Hindsight"

Answer (score 3):

1. > There's something about Mary
2. > Pushin Tin